# Is there a best practice for dropping dupes from a dataframe with many, many columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am merging two dataframes with quite a few columns and the IDs are repeating in one dataframe, so I'm getting a lot of dupes in the merged dataframe. I'm wondering if there is a best way to figure out which columns are actual dupes and leverage that logic to drop dupes.

I'm doing this...

```
df_final = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['field1', 'field2','field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6'], keep='first')
```

There are many more fields. If I add too few, I don't get enough records dropped and if I add too many, or the wrong ones, I get too many records dropped. How can I figure out what's a true dupe and not a dupe and drop only dupes? Finally, the first dataframe has around 31k records and the second has around 9k records. I would expect the df_final to have around 31k records.

Comment: It feels as if it makes more sense to prevent this in the first place, by altering the merging. Is that not an option?

Comment: 31K columns, or 31K rows?

Comment: sounds like you need to re-shape your dataframe. can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: What is an example of altering a merge?

Comment: How would reshaping help? It's wide, and I can easily make it long, but I don't understand, offhand, how that would make things better.